# Difference between vCenter and vSphere

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

What is the difference between vCenter and vSphere?
And which one should I use if I want to access a list of VMs and templates?
Will they have different IP addresses?

Answer (score 2):

vCenter is a **server** that manages VMs, datastores, hosts, etc...

vSphere is an **app** that enables you to talk with the vCenter Server. You can use vSphere to send commands to vCenter and vCenter manages your infrastructure with these commands.

Comment: This link will be helpful maybe:

http://stackzilla.com/what-is-the-difference-between-vmware-esx-esxi-vsphere-and-vcenter/

Answer (score 0):

the vSphere vCenter Server is a central managing unit for all your vSphere ESXi Hosts.
If you want to deploy Templates with Guest customization you need to use the vCenter Server.

The vCenter Server can be a seperate hardware Server or a virtual machine - so vCenter and ESXi have different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only managing a single host, vSphere client is simple to use. If your virtual environment consists of multiple hosts, vCenter allows you to manage all of them in one interface.